# Angular dynamic internationalization with multiple file-encodings

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have an angular app that is functioning well for two languages (English and French). I can compile for production, and dynamically switch between languages just by going to the index.html of the respected compilation output.

However, I now need to be able to support Japanese which is a double-byte character set (UTF-16) whereas English and French are both (UTF-8).

ChatGPT told me to make a index.html file for each language (index.<language>.html), so that I can change the following properties:

```html
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

However, I'm not sure how to configure the angular.json file to tell it to use different index.html files for each language.

I'm also not married to the idea of multiple index.html files. If someone knows how to solve this in a better way I'm all ears.

Also, here's a condensed version of my angular.json

```json
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      ...
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en",
        "locales": {
          "fr": {
            "translation": "src/locale/fr.json"
          },
          "jis": {
            "translation": "src/locale/jis.json"
          }
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "index": "src/index.html",
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "localize": ["en", "fr", "jis"],
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "6mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "7kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            ...
          },
          ...
        },
        ...
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```